# How to remove newline character between two strings <font>\n</font> in unix?

Tags: text-processing, sed, newlines, html

I want to remove the newline between two html tags which exists as follows:

```
<font>
</font>
```

I want to remove the newline character such that it becomes:

```
<font></font>
```

Also, there might be cases where there are more than one newline(s):

```
<font>

</font>
```

That also I want to remove to make it look like:

```
<font></font>
```

One more scenario,

if the pattern is like:

```
<font>
This is a text
</font>
```

After, conversion it should become:

```
<font>This is a text</font>
```

All the above scenarios are resolved, if we just truncate **only** the newline between two html tags. We should not be considering any white spaces.

There are couple of ways I have found it using sed, but it is very time consuming and very very efficient performance wise, particularly if the file has 1000+ html tags.

Comment: add the `sed` solutions to question, it'll help others in giving a suitable answer

Comment: It is the same as mentioned below by Serge.

Answer (score 2):

This `sed` command should help you:

```
sed -e ':1;/<font>[[:space:]]*$/{N;s#<font>[[:space:]]\+</font>#<font></font>#g;b1}' file
```

The command is looking for `<font>` tag that is followed by whitespace up to the end of line. Then the next line is pulled into the pattern space; then the replacement of a possibly existing sequence `<font>[[:space:]]\+</font>` is performed and script restarts from the beginning. If the pattern space does not match the address `/<font>[[:space:]]*$/`, i.e. some non-space content is present after a `<font>` tag, then the pattern space is printed out and cleared by the `end of sed script` and the process restarts.

**Edit**:
Performance measurement.

I filled a file with the following content repeated 10k times:

```
<font>
dejidewji
</font>
<font>



</font><font>





</font>
```

totally, 620Kb.
The timings of the script above on 1.4Gz A8-4500M are:

```
real    0m0.361s
user    0m0.356s
sys 0m0.005s
```

**Edit2**:

Your last question update is much easier solved by `perl` and performance is 10 times better, as showed the other answer:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's|<font>\s+|<font>|g;s|\s+</font>|</font>|g' file
```

Credits to @spasic

Comment: But will it remove the newline between the two tags: <font></font> ? I have doubt on it as you are using just one tag <font> as a reference. What if the tags are in the pattern <font>\n<b>\nSome Text</b></font>

Comment: @RonitMishra check the update. Let me know if performance is acceptable

Comment: @RonitMishra you didn't mention anything in your question about there being text between the two tags. Please update it if you're changing the scope.

Comment: @Serge: Thanks for your quick response. I will try it out and let you know. My bad, i thought that it might be obvious to have text between two font tags. One quick question for you, the text between <font> remains intact right ? only the newline is affected?

Comment: @RonitMishra New lines and spaces if there are only new lines and spaces

Comment: @Serge: Ok. So if the pattern is like <font>\n This is a text </font>, this will become <font>Thisisatext</font> ?

Comment: @Serge: Updated the question for your kind consideration.

Comment: @RonitMishra no

Comment: @Serge: I tried executing your command with the example <font>\n This is a text </font> but nothing happened. But when i executed for the pattern <font>\n  </font>, it worked. So i think your solution is partially working but might fail in the above mentioned scenario.

Comment: @RonitMishra it was not designed to work with <f>text</f> cases. BTW see the update. I Think you have plenty of idea now

Comment: @Serge: I don't know why but the command perl -0777 -pe 's|<font>\n*([^\n]*)\n*</font>|<font>$1</font>|g' myfile.html doesn't do anything. Is there any scenario where the perl command doesn't work?

Comment: it is unlikely that you have `perl` uninstalled, but still, what `which perl` and `perl -v` returns?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.html
<font>
This is a text
</font>

123

<font>
</font>

xyz

<font>

</font>

ijk

<font>





</font>

789
```

`perl` solution, `-0777` slurps entire file

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's|<font>\n*([^\n]*)\n*</font>|<font>$1</font>|g' ip.html
<font>This is a text</font>

123

<font></font>

xyz

<font></font>

ijk

<font></font>

789
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but your example isn't working at all even for a simple scenario like <html>
</font>
This is a text
<font>
</html>

Comment: what is the output of `file myfile.html`... does `perl -pe 's/font/XYZ/g' myfile.html` change anything?

Comment: Yes it changes <font> to <XYZ>

Comment: copy sample file from the answer and see if command works.. if so, there is something in your file not known to us causing the issue.. you may copy paste few lines from your file to question on which we can test it.. other than that, I have no idea